# How to iterate through HTMLCollection in Javascript/Babel

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs, htmlcollection

I am trying to set up a website using webpack and Babel. 
I am trying assign an "onclick" event to all of items inside of a table using jQuery. I am selecting all "clickable-row" table row items using `getElementsByClassName` which returns an HTMLCollection but when calling `.length` of it, it returns 0. Printing out the collection to console shows that there are items inside of it. Which leads me to thinking it's a Babel problem.

I tried converting it to an Array - the array is empty.
Tried `document.querySelectorAll();` which returns empty NodeList and the `...` operator,
tried using `.forEach()` and tried using `HTMLCollection.prototype.forEach = Array.prototype.forEach;` none of which lead anywhere.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
$('document').ready(getTableRows);

function getTableRows() {
    let tableRows = document.getElementsByClassName("clickable-row");
    console.log(tableRows);
    console.log("Length of this collection = " + tableRows.length);
    let array = Array.from(tableRows);
    console.log("Converted to array");
    console.log(array);
}
```

Here is the result returned by console in google chrome:

```
HTMLCollection []
    0: tr.clickable-row
    1: tr.clickable-row
    2: tr.clickable-row
    3: tr.clickable-row
    4: tr.clickable-row
    5: tr.clickable-row
    6: tr.clickable-row
    7: tr.clickable-row
    8: tr.clickable-row
    9: tr.clickable-row
    length: 10
    __proto__: HTMLCollection

Length of this collection = 0

Converted to array
[]
    length: 0
    __proto__: Array(0)
```

I tried recreating the same thing in jsfiddle but it didn't cause the same behaviour which leads me to think even more it's a Babel/webpack thing. 
http://jsfiddle.net/h2emxdf1/2/

Sorry if I mixed things up but I am a newbie if it comes to this whole webpack thing.

Comment: [`get​Elements​ByClass​Name` returns a *live* collection of found elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName). So I would assume that in the moment when your code runs, it did not find any matching elements. But later it does and updates the list accordingly. Note that the console does *not* necessarily reflect the state of objects back when you logged them but only in the moment of when you expanded them.

Comment: To verify str's idea, change your first line to this one: $('document').ready(function() { setTimeout(getTableRows, 5000); }); and wait 5s after opening the page to see the results on the console.

Comment: Thanks to both of you I came to the knowledge that js executes functions asynchronously which was exactly what str pointed out. I managed to figure it out by creating a callback. If you posted your comment as an answer I could flag it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @str I realized that js executes functions asynchronously which was indeed the problem in my case. So I created a callback. Now it works as it should be.